# Spring Boot OAuth2 - How to access Refresh Token to save for later

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to use the Eclipse's package for accessing GitHub using their client `GitHubClient`.

One of the methods on the client is `setOAuth2Token`, it takes a String token. I am *assuming* this is a refresh token.

Either way, I am able to login using GitHub with Spring OAuth2, but I am not sure how to retrieve the refresh token. I can retrieve the bearer token:

```
@GetMapping()
public PingResponse ping(@Autowired Principal principal) {

OAuth2Authentication userDetails = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
OAuth2AuthenticationDetails userOAuthDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) userDetails.getDetails();
OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails protectedUserDetails = (OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails) principal;


logger.info("user details: " + userDetails);
logger.info("user details credentials: " + userDetails.getCredentials());
logger.info("oauth user details: " + userOAuthDetails);
logger.info("token type: " + userOAuthDetails.getTokenType());
logger.info("token value: " + userOAuthDetails.getTokenValue());
logger.info("decoded details: " + userOAuthDetails.getDecodedDetails());
logger.info("Ping on the server was successful.");

return new PingResponse("Connection is successful!");
}
```

However, I can't seem to get at the refresh token.

I'd like to get it so I can save it in a DB to do action on user's behalf *later on*, without the user logged in.

How do I get at the refresh token so I can save it for later?

Thanks!